# Cachable : How can we use static field of other class as Key in Spring Caching

Tags: java, spring, caching

How can we use static field of other class as Key in @Cachable

```
class Keys {
    public static String CACHE_KEY = 'MY_KEY';
}

class MyClass {

@Cachable(value="TestValue",key="#Keys.CACHE_KEY")
public void method(){

}

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a keyGenerator instead, although you wouldn't want a constant key obviously.

```
   @Cachable(value="TestValue",keyGenerator ="keyGenerator")
    public void method(){

    }

    @Bean
    public KeyGenerator keyGenerator() {
      return new KeyGenerator() {
        @Override
        public Object generate(Object o, Method method, Object... params) {
          return CACHE_KEY ;
        }
      };
    }
```

Comment: Thanks Essex, 
I am looking for some generic solution, as i have say 10 static keys that needs to be use and i don't want to create 10 key generator class

Comment: You don't need to create 10 key generator classes, use one that has some logic in it.